# Run a bash command from rmarkdown in windows using r variables

Tags: r, r-markdown, wsl-2

I am running DADA2 on my data, and for primer triming I need cutadapt to be installed on my machine (Windows 11). As I could not install it on windows, I did it on my WSL and I am trying to use this installed version in my commad through rmarkdown which is used in Windows.

When running a bash chunk to verify the version of cutadapt it works

````
```{bash}
cutadapt--version
```
````

> 3.5

However, when I use the following command

````
```{bash}
sh windows_path_to_bash_script R_variable1 R_variable2 R_variable3 windows_path_to_log_file
```
````

It keeps running without generating any files.

Any help would be much appreciated.